# Conditionally lock a cell in Google Sheets if Cell A > Cell B

Tags: google-sheets

this is my first question here and I'm an absolute newbie when it comes to Google Sheets and especially with scripts.

Anyway, I've created a spreadsheet in which you can chose a certain Soccer/European Football player in (just for example) Cell L9 from a dropdown menu. Every player has a certain kickoff time that is (in this example) written in Cell AD33 (the format is yymmddHHmmss). Additionally, I have inserted the "Now()"-function in the same format in Cell O30, which refreshes every minute.

What I want to do now, is to *automatically protect Cell L9* (the player) *from any further changes, eg. protect it, if the current time shown in O30 is bigger than their kickoff time in AD33*. (eg if(AD33>O30; LOCK CELL L9)).
Unfortunately I have searched for a solution on Google and this forum for hours and cannot find a solution.

Is there any way to do this? Either through a function or through a script?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the level of security required a Custom formula for a validation rule *might* be sufficient:

```
=and(AD33>O30,or(L9="a",L9="b",L9="c",L9="d"))
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, etc are the players' names.

Comment: Hey and thank you for the quick response. The problem with that solution however is that the kickoff time in AD33 is only being filled in as soon as you select the player in L9. AD33 looks like that:  IF(L9=A2[Player 1];C2[Kickoff Player 1]; IF(L9=A3[Player 2];C3[Kickoff Player 2].... and so on)). 

In this sense, I do not want to interfere with the possibility to further select someone else, but rather lock the cell down with the player that was chosen ahead of their respective kickoff time.